# Python language reasons for NaN (other than dividing by zero)

Tags: python, nan

I am at rather a loss at the moment, I have a program that works well for most parameters, but for some parameters it throws a NaN exception. The problem seems to lie in calculating values slightly larger than 1. I have a function that is something like this f(x,t), for large values of x, f increases rapidly with t and there is no issue, however for small values of x f increases very slowly with t. For small values of x it doesn't work at all going something like this (array representing discrete time steps):

```
1.0
1.0
1.0
NaN
```

I don't understand how NaN is returned for values that clearly aren't tending away to infinity, and are slightly greater than 1. Is there some data type problem that might throw this exception?

For larger values of x the behavior might be something like this:

```
1.0
1.000000000000074
1.000000000000486
1.000000000000888
```

and so on with no issues at all.

Comment: We would have to see your code to be able to comment ...

Comment: There's nothing we can say without seeing the actual code. BTW: there's nothing wrong with data types itself. The only thing that might be wrong is the way you use them.

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: More precisely, please share a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Don't share all the code. No one wants to wade through 60 lines of stuff to find the problem.

Comment: Sorry people, I've spent the last three hours working on the program (which was over 300 lines so I didn't think it would be fair to post it here). I have eventually found a 0/0, I was just wondering in the question if anything else other than dividing by zero (or in general something that is mathematically undefined) to cause this. Anyway if there is, my code is not an example.

Answer (score 1):

[PEP 754](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0754/) specifically indicates PositiveInfinty/PositiveInfinity will return NaN.  (And talks about using PosInf = 1e300000 as a value for PositiveInfinity but also points out this isn't portable or non-ugly)

[The wiki page for IEEE 754 NaN's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) indicates the following additional examples:

- Operations with a NaN as at least one operand.
- Indeterminate forms

  - The divisions 0/0 and ±∞/±∞ (as mentioned in your question and above respectively)
  - The multiplications 0×±∞ and ±∞×0
  - The additions ∞ + (−∞), (−∞) + ∞ and equivalent subtractions
  - The standard has alternative functions for powers:

    - The standard `pow` function and the integer exponent `pown` function define 0^0, 1∞, and ∞0 as 1. (Note that 0**0 which I would expect to either use or at least be similar to pow in python 2.7 returns 1)
    - The `powr` function defines all three indeterminate forms as invalid operations and so returns NaN.
    - Real operations with complex results, for example: [which for all the ones I tried, using math.sqrt, math.log, math.asin instead throw Math Domain Error in python versus returning NaN)]

      - The square root of a negative number.
      - The logarithm of a negative number
      - The inverse sine or cosine of a number that is less than −1 or greater than +1.